# Tag cleanup request [aliased]

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [aliased](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/aliased) is described as "Things that have effect from anti-aliasing."  Only three questions asked;  two about aliasing shown in fonts (and both tagged with [fonts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/fonts) as well).  The remaining one has nothing to do with "anti-aliasing" thing... it referred to file aliases.

Suggest to remove the tag as it's rarely used, covered by other tags and createed confusion.

Comment: I don't think blacklisting is warranted, so I removed the tag.

Answer (score 3):

I agree, this tag is very ambiguous, and probably meta as well.

I've removed the tag from the 3 questions that had it, it should be removed within the next 24 hours.

Comment: why is it that we can't do this with the install tag as well?

Comment: @sbergeron a) the only current way to do this is manual retagging. Retagging thousands of questions at once is a painful business and there are much better things to do with your time on the site. Not to mention you would flood the front page with old stuff.

Comment: it doesn't have any use cases at the moment as it is blacklisted at this point, right?

Comment: @sbergeron Yes, it is blacklisted so no new questions with this tag can be added and no edits can be approved without removing the tag. It will eventually go down on its own, with a *little* (i.e., no mass retag parties) help from us.

Answer (score 2):

Only 3 questions with the tag, and sincerely, that was a bad, *very bad* tag name. I don't think there are enough issues in the site to merit a tag.

- [Issue with font rendering inside applications](https://askubuntu.com/q/300891/169736)
- [Aliases: difference between .bash_rc, .bash_aliases and /usr/local/bin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2528/aliases-difference-between-bash-rc-bash-aliases-and-usr-local-bin)
- [How can I fix my problems with fonts in Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557/how-can-i-fix-my-problems-with-fonts-in-firefox)